# ISAPI Redirect Issue. ColdFusion 11

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, isapi-redirect

My laptop died and I had to set up everything afresh on a new one. Everything has gone smoothly till I tried to browse a website I had running on the old laptop. The home page loaded fine and database and everything connected. However, when I browsed to a page that required a login and would normally redirect me to the login page, the following error occurred:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
>   Requested URL    http://zbay_sys:80/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll
>   Physical Path
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\zbay_sys\jakarta\isapi_redirect.dll

I was running CF9 on the old laptop, but thought I might as well upgrade to CF11 in the process.

So, I'm running ColdFusion 11 on IIS Windows 10.
I used Web Platform Installer to install ISAPI redirect module.

I only have a basic knowledge of IIS and ISAPI stuff and am struggling to debug this.

There is no Jakarta virtual directory. Should this have been created automatically?

Comment: OK, I manually added the jakarta virtual directory and this appears to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Manually adding the jakarta virtual directory fixed the issue